# A general multi user / multi assets adminitration model

Tags: data-modeling, business-logic, datamodel

Im looking for a general "multi user with multi assets adminitration" databasemodel.
Especially i would like to know how to best handle the "rights".

Let me describe my problem and question using github as sample.

github has
- many users
- many repositories

In github you can create a repository and then grant rights on your repository to other users.

What does a model look like, that "answers the question":
What users are granted rights to what repository.

My first idea was to create a "Team"-Table.
When a User gets signed up, and creates a repository there is always created a team-record for that repository.
That team has only got one member (the user it selves).
Granting a new (second) user, rights on a repository, is accomplished by making the new (scond) user a member of the team for that repository.

Has any one of you done anything like this before?

I would appreciate any hints.
Perhaps i have overseen something important in my first sketch.